# Using Tensorflow to perform chain rule

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, gradient

I just read through Tensorflow Docs, and found that `tf.gradients(tf.gradients(ys, xs, grad_ys=None, name='gradients', colocate_gradients_with_ops=False, gate_gradients=False, aggregation_method=None)` could be used for computing the gradients with respects to `dy/dx`. Currently, I want to compute the gradients of `dz(f(x))/dx` (which should be decomposed as `dz/df * df/dx` using the chain rule), and I wonder if there is a way in Tensorflow to do this chain rule. I also wonder what it means in terms of `grad_ys is a list of Tensor, holding the gradients received by the ys. The list must be the same length as ys.` in Tensorflow Doc.

Comment: Tensorflow will do the chain rule for you. You just tell it what variables you want the gradient for and it will compute it.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But if the tensorflow graphs for computing `dz/df` and `df/dx` is disconnected, I cannot simply tell Tensorflow to use chain rule, so I have to manually do it. For example, the input `y` for `z(y)` is a placeholder, and we use the output of `f(x)` to feed into placeholder `y`. In this case, the graphs for computing `z(y)` and `f(x)` are disconnected.

Comment: Why not connect the graphs?

Comment: In the current implementation of my algorithm, I cannot connect them, as connecting them breaks up my algorithm. And Yes, if the graphs are connected, computing the gradient will obviously be simple.

Answer (score 1):

suppose your loss function is loss
and x is the value you want the gradients for.

suppose your output of function which you want to multiply as in chainrule is dz do

```
tf.gradients(loss,x, grad_ys=dz)
```

I hope this solves the problem